# IE 11, XMLHttpRequest, xhr.upload no set in a Webworker

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-worker, xmlhttprequest-level2

while trying to code an upload library in JavaScrupt I ended with a weird problem on IE 11.

With XMLHttpRequest 2, you can upload files and get the progress. However, if you are trying to do so in a webworker, you won't get any progress from IE 11 (I tried only this version). You will get an error with the same code.

Here an example :

worker.js

```
self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {

    var file = e.data;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr.upload)
       xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event){
          // here we get the progression through event.loaded
    };

    xhr.open('POST', '/upload.php', true);
    xhr.send(file);

});
```

main.js

```
var uploadworker = new Worker('worker.js');
uploadworker.postMessage( file );
```

If you use this code directly, it will work on any browser. If you use it in a webworker, it will not work in IE11. If fact you will get an "Invalid argument" on the line : `if (xhr.upload)`
Because IE11 doesn't seem to have this property set when XMLHttpRequest is used in a webworker.

Anybody has an idea why this happens ?

Comment: Did you use exactly this code? Could it be that xhr is declared in the wrong scope when you use it in a webworker? Can you show the full(er) code including the webworker?

Comment: Yes GolezTrol  it's the exact code. I updated my post with all details of my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Anybody has an idea why this happens?

That's because it was a [bug](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/107521/), that has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: I am using IE11, and facing the same issue, Any help ?

Comment: @Jerry As mentioned in the link provided, it was fixed in Edge 15.15002.

Comment: I am using 11.0.9600.19035 , I am still facing the issue